# Scroll (Rolar Tela) com Selenium em Python: Erro

Tags: python, python-3.x, rolamento, selenium-webdriver

Possuo uma lista de itens na tela, nos quais preciso clicar um a um para parse de dados. Ocorre que, em determinado momento, o Selenium não consegue mais clicar, pois quando tenta, o seguinte erro acontece:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point
```

Estou tentando fazer com que a tela vá sendo rolada paulatinamente a cada iteração, porém não estou tendo sucesso. Quando executo a linha abaixo

```
browser.execute_script('window.scroll(0, 200)')
```

A tela rola, para em seguida apresentar o erro

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
```

Na sequência qualquer nova tentativa de rolagem é ignorada. Alguma sugestão de como proceder para contorno da situação?

Comment: Estou percebendo que ele rola a tela pra uma determinada posição. Como eu faria pra rolar a tela X vezes??? Certamente é esse o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri mais uma (scrollBy):

```
try:
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 15)')
except:
    None
```

Fiz dessa forma pra contornar o erro, o qual ainda não entendo porque ocorre. Mas foi suficiente pra contornar o problema.